how can I display a value associated with a selected item in a thymeleaf html page
I'm using spring boot to serve some thymeleaf HTML pages. On one of the pages I have a drop down of options, and when an option is selected I want to display another field with the data from the selected item but I keep getting an error
EL1008E: Property or field 'shareid' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?
HTML snippet
<h1>Share input</h1>
<form action = "#" th:action="@{/shareInput}"  method="POST">
    <select name="shareName" required>
        <option value="">--Select name of share--</option>
        <th:block th:each="shares : ${share}">
        <option th:value="${shares.shareid}" th:text="${shares.shareName}">    
        </option>
        </th:block>
    </select>
    <br>

    <div th:if="*{share.shareid > 0}">
        <label for="amountInvested">Current value:</label>
        <input type="number" th:text="${share.amountInvested}" id="amountInvested" name="amountInvested">
        <br>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



If I comment out the 'div' section the code works fine and displays a drop down of available shares. I'm basically trying to get whatever is in the 'amountInvested' field for the share I select to populate.
I've tried various combinations in the th:if statement but keep getting the same error.
